# L5 - Why it takes so long? Any suggestion better?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, laravel-5

I have this code in my controller

```
    /* 1 */
    $header = DB::table('rekap_cmd')->select('date','uniqueid')->groupBy('date')->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->get();
    $header = json_decode(json_encode($header), true);
    foreach($header as $names => $specs){
        /* 2 */
        $datax = DB::table('rekap_cmd')->where('uniqueid', $specs['uniqueid'])->get();
        $datax = json_decode(json_encode($datax), true);
        foreach($datax as $namess => $specss) {
            $datetime = new DateTime($specss['date']);
            $header[$names]['datetime']['date'] = $datetime->format('d-m-Y');
            $header[$names]['datetime']['time'] = $datetime->format('H:i');
        }
    }
    /* 3 */
    $data = DB::table('group_symbol')->select('symbol','alias')->where('for_surya', 1)->groupBy('alias')->get();
    $data = json_decode(json_encode($data), true);
    $odd='odd';
    foreach($data as $names => $specs) {
        if($odd=='odd'){
            $odd='even';
        }
        else{
            $odd='odd';
        }
        foreach($header as $namess => $specss) {
            /* 4 */
            $datax = DB::table('rekap_cmd')->where('uniqueid', $specss['uniqueid'])->where('symbol', $specs['alias'])->first();
            $data[$names]['data'] = [];
            $data[$names]['data']['class'] = $odd;
            if($datax){
                $data[$names]['data']['buy'] = ($datax->buy)/100;
                $data[$names]['data']['sell'] = ($datax->sell)/100;
            }
            else{
                $data[$names]['data']['buy'] = null;
                $data[$names]['data']['sell'] = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Explanation :
1 = It will show 2507 rows (it only takes 0.086s to show the result in PHPMyAdmin)
2 = It will show 12 rows in average (it only takes 0.014s to show the result in PHPMyAdmin)
3 = It will show 30 rows (it only takes 0.024s to show the result in PHPMyAdmin)
4 = It will show 1 row (it only takes 0.000..s to show the result in PHPMyAdmin)
But in the end this code spent **18 MINUTES** in total!
Can someone explain why it takes so long to run? Anyone have suggestion to do better?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you on development or production?

Comment: `json_decode(json_encode($data), true);` something like this costs much. Leave that things and play with plain array, that should gets you better.

Comment: @revo development, what's different?

Comment: @Chay22 i've tried it, it only cost around 1s.

Comment: I'm not sure yet. Chay22 also made a valid point. Although I don't think it's culprit here, there are many unnecessary `json_decode`/`json_encode` calls which without them you have the same access over rows too: [The get method returns an array of results where each result is an instance of the PHP `StdClass` object.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries). Did you try to use PHP's `microtime()` to find the block that causes this long-lasting process?

Comment: @revo i don't know, but when i remove all the foreach and point no.2 & 4 it only takes around 3s. (including json encode and decode)

Comment: @revo yh, i'm using microtime to know the exact time.

Comment: Use `microtime()` before and after ***each*** `foreach` block then check which one takes much more time to get done. You may also separate these lines to more blocks besides applying `microtime()`.

Comment: @revo ah okay, i will try it now.

Comment: @revo microtime result > 1st foreach = 45.909916162491, 2nd foreach = 1105.8181359768

Comment: You have 4 `foreach`es. You need more informative `microtime()` outputs. You can take advantage of xdebug as well.